# Configuration network in raspberry with 2 interfaces

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi

There is a raspberry with two interfaces, one interface is connected to a router(ip 192.168.1.100, the other to TV (this interface always has a static ip 192.168.1.1). How to configure such a subnet so that TV has access to the Internet through a router and you can beat it by IPv4 on the router network (now it is possible only on IPv6, IPv4 is active on the raspberry network)